# Is it possible to give PDB name to a procedure and select from it?

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c

The following example is not working, I just trying to show what I'm trying to do.

Given table:

```
-- this table is located at the CDB
create table t1 (tab_name varchar2(35))
/
-- this proc is located at the CDB
Create or replace procedure FindTables(vPdb in varchar2, vOwner in varchar2)
BEGIN
  insert into t1(tab_name) select TABLE_NAME from ALL_TABLES@vPdb where OWNER=vOwner;
END;
/
```

Is there a way to create a temporary DB link or something like that? or any other way?

**EDIT**

I need also a solution for user tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but this is just wrong. A dblink can not be provided as a parameter like that. And a dblink is not required at all for this.

You can access information about all tables in all PDBs using the `CDB_TABLES` view.

[CDB_* Views](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/cdb_-views.html#GUID-2B8A1B8B-4F5B-4FBB-AE0B-68B6F8BA7D5E)

> For every DBA_* view, a CDB_* view is defined. In the root of a
> multitenant container database (CDB), CDB_* views can be used to
> obtain information about tables, tablespaces, users, privileges,
> parameters, and so on contained in the root and in pluggable databases
> (PDBs).

```
SQL> show con_name;

CON_NAME
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT
SQL> show pdbs

    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 PDB1                           READ WRITE NO
         4 PDB2                           READ WRITE NO

SQL> select table_name from cdb_tables t join v$containers c on t.con_id = c.con_id
     where c.name = 'PDB1' and t.owner = 'BP';

no rows selected

SQL> select table_name from cdb_tables t join v$containers c on t.con_id = c.con_id
     where c.name = 'PDB2' and t.owner = 'BP';

TABLE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
T1

SQL>
```

You can easily provide the PDB name and table owner as parameters to a query like above.

Comment: What about select from a regular table from PDB? is it possible?